# Flutter app cannot receive udp packets from cpp code

Tags: c++, flutter, udp, send, receiver

Basically we're trying to create a gps nav system via priority queue and dijkstra's algo and flutter sends input of two example cities to the c++ code where the cities have predefined weights and is present as a mesh. The fastest route is processed, stored and ideally sent back to flutter.

however while the cpp code has the output ready and is ready to be sent the code either doesn't send or the flutter code doesn't receive.

The flutter code is able to send the current city and the destination city to the cpp code and the cpp code is able to process those and print it in the terminal. The problem is when the cpp code tries to send the shortest path string back to the flutter app.

---CPP---

```
#include <iostream>

#include <string>

#include <cstring>

#include <cstdlib>

#include <cerrno>

#include <unistd.h>

#include <sys/types.h>

#include <sys/socket.h>

#include <netinet/in.h>

#include <arpa/inet.h>

#include <unordered_map>

#include <vector>

#include <algorithm>



using namespace std;



const int PORT = 8746;



class Node {

public:

    string data;

    int priority;

    Node* next;



    Node(string val, int prio) {

        data = val;

        priority = prio;

        next = nullptr;

    }

};



class PriorityQueue {

private:

    Node* front;



public:

    PriorityQueue() {

        front = nullptr;

    }



    void push(string value, int priority) {

        Node* newNode = new Node(value, priority);

        if (!front || priority < front->priority) {

            newNode->next = front;

            front = newNode;

        } else {

            Node* current = front;

            while (current->next && current->next->priority <= priority) {

                current = current->next;

            }

            newNode->next = current->next;

            current->next = newNode;

        }

    }



    string pop() {

        if (!front) {

            return ""; // You can return a special value or throw an error if needed

        }

        string value = front->data;

        Node* temp = front;

        front = front->next;

        delete temp;

        return value;

    }



    bool isEmpty() {

        return front == nullptr;

    }

};



class Graph {

    unordered_map<string, unordered_map<string, int>> adjList;



public:

    void addEdge(string src, string dest, int weight) {

        adjList[src][dest] = weight;

        adjList[dest][src] = weight; // Assuming an undirected graph

    }



    pair<vector<string>, vector<int>> dijkstra(string src, string dest, int& totalWeight) {

        unordered_map<string, int> distances;

        unordered_map<string, pair<string, int>> previous;

        PriorityQueue customPriorityQueue;



        for (const auto& pair : adjList) {

            distances[pair.first] = INT_MAX;

        }



        distances[src] = 0;

        customPriorityQueue.push(src, 0);



        while (!customPriorityQueue.isEmpty()) {

            string curr = customPriorityQueue.pop();



            if (curr == dest) {

                vector<string> path;

                vector<int> edgeWeights;

                totalWeight = 0;

                while (previous.find(curr) != previous.end()) {

                    path.push_back(curr);

                    edgeWeights.push_back(previous[curr].second);

                    totalWeight += edgeWeights.back();

                    curr = previous[curr].first;

                }

                path.push_back(src);

                reverse(path.begin(), path.end());

                reverse(edgeWeights.begin(), edgeWeights.end());

                return {path, edgeWeights};

            }



            for (const auto& neighbor : adjList[curr]) {

                int weight = neighbor.second;

                if (distances[curr] + weight < distances[neighbor.first]) {

                    distances[neighbor.first] = distances[curr] + weight;

                    previous[neighbor.first] = {curr, weight};

                    customPriorityQueue.push(neighbor.first, distances[neighbor.first]);

                }

            }

        }



        return {{}, {}};

    }

};



int main() {

    // Create a UDP socket

    int serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

    if (serverSocket < 0) {

        std::cerr << "Error opening socket: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;

        return 1;

    }



    // Bind the socket to an address and port

    sockaddr_in serverAddress;

    sockaddr_in clientAddress;

    serverAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;

    serverAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    serverAddress.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    

    if (::bind(serverSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&serverAddress, sizeof(serverAddress)) < 0) {

        std::cerr << "Error binding socket: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;

        return 1;

    }



    cout << "Listening for UDP packets on port " << PORT << endl;



    char buffer[1024];

    socklen_t serveraddresslen = sizeof(serverAddress);

    socklen_t clientAddrLen = sizeof(clientAddress);

    



    // Create a graph and add edges between cities with weights

    Graph cityGraph;

    cityGraph.addEdge("New_York", "Chicago", 800);

    cityGraph.addEdge("New_York", "Los_Angeles", 2500);

    cityGraph.addEdge("New_York", "Miami", 1300);

    cityGraph.addEdge("Chicago", "Los_Angeles", 1800);

    cityGraph.addEdge("Chicago", "Miami", 1200);

    cityGraph.addEdge("Chicago", "Seattle", 2000);

    cityGraph.addEdge("Los_Angeles", "Miami", 2800);

    cityGraph.addEdge("Los_Angeles", "San_Francisco", 500);

    cityGraph.addEdge("San_Francisco", "Las_Vegas", 800);

    cityGraph.addEdge("Las_Vegas", "Denver", 1000);

    cityGraph.addEdge("Denver", "Houston", 1500);

    cityGraph.addEdge("Miami", "Houston", 1100);



    while (true) {

        // Receive data from clients

        ssize_t bytesReceived = recvfrom(serverSocket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&clientAddress, &clientAddrLen);

        if (bytesReceived < 0) {

            cerr << "Error receiving data: " << strerror(errno) << endl;

            return 1;

        }



        // Convert the client's IP address to a printable string

        char clientIpStr[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];

        inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(clientAddress.sin_addr), clientIpStr, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);

        

        std::cout << "Received: " << buffer << " from " << clientIpStr << std::endl;

        // Parse the received message

        buffer[bytesReceived] = '\0';

        string receivedMessage(buffer);



        // Extract source and destination cities from the message

        size_t delimiterPos = receivedMessage.find(',');

        if (delimiterPos == string::npos) {

            cerr << "Invalid message format: " << receivedMessage << endl;

            continue;

        }



        string srcCity = receivedMessage.substr(0, delimiterPos);

        string destCity = receivedMessage.substr(delimiterPos + 1);



        int totalWeight = 0;

        // Find the shortest path between cities using Dijkstra's algorithm

        auto [shortestPath, edgeWeights] = cityGraph.dijkstra(srcCity, destCity, totalWeight);



        // Construct a response message

        string responseMessage = "Shortest path from " + srcCity + " to " + destCity + ": ";

        for (size_t i = 0; i < shortestPath.size(); ++i) {

            responseMessage += shortestPath[i];

            if (i < edgeWeights.size()) {

                responseMessage += " (Distance: " + to_string(edgeWeights[i]) + ")";

            }

            if (i < shortestPath.size() - 1) {

                responseMessage += " -> ";

            }

        }

        responseMessage += "\nTotal distance: " + to_string(totalWeight);



        // Send the response back to the client

        sendto(serverSocket, responseMessage.c_str(), responseMessage.length(), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&clientAddress, clientAddrLen);



        cout << "Received: " << receivedMessage << " from " << clientIpStr << endl;

        cout << "Sent response: " << responseMessage << " to " << clientIpStr << endl;

    }



    // Close the socket (this won't be reached in this example)

    close(serverSocket);



    return 0;

}
```

---FLUTTER---

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:udp/udp.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var sender;
  var receiver;
  var reciverr;
  String ipAddress = "192.168.29.32"; // Default IP address
  int port = 8746;// Default port
  var cities=["Los_Angeles", "Seattle","Denver", "Dallas", "Chicago", "New_York", "Miami", "San_Francisco"];
  String selectedCurrent = "Los_Angeles";
  String selectedDestination = "Seattle";

  String receivedData = ""; // Add this variable to store received data

  final TextEditingController ipAddressController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController portController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    sender.close();
    receiver.close();
    super.dispose();
  }


  //   // Receiving/listening
  void _initialize() async {
    try {
      // Set the ipAddress to the loopback address (127.0.0.1)
      ipAddress = "127.0.0.1";

      // Retrieve the port from the portController
      final portText = portController.text;


      // Create a UDP instance and bind it to the loopback address and port.
      sender = await UDP.bind(Endpoint.any(port: Port(int.parse(portText))));

      // Create a new UDP instance and bind it to the loopback address and port.
      receiver = await UDP.bind(Endpoint.loopback(port: Port(int.parse(portText))));

      receiver.asStream().listen((datagram) {
        if (datagram != null) {
          var str = String.fromCharCodes(datagram.data);
          print("Received: $str");

          // Update the receivedData variable with the received string
          setState(() {
            receivedData = str;
          });
        }
      }).onError((error) {
        print("Error: $error");
      });
      print("UDP initialized");
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error initializing UDP communication: $e');
    }
  }




  void _sendData() async {
    // Retrieve IP address and port from TextFields
    ipAddress = ipAddressController.text;
    int port;
    try {
      port = int.parse(portController.text);
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error parsing port: $e');
      // Set a default port if the parsed port is invalid.
      port = 80;
    }
    // Create an endpoint with the specified IP address and port
    final endpoint = Endpoint.unicast(InternetAddress(ipAddress), port: Port(port));

    // Create a UDP instance and bind it to the specified IP address and port
    sender = await UDP.bind(Endpoint.any(port: Port(port)));
    String dataa = selectedCurrent + ',' + selectedDestination;

    // Send a simple string to the specified IP address and port using the created endpoint
    var dataLength = await sender.send(
      dataa.codeUnits,
      endpoint,
    );

    print('$dataLength bytes sent.');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('UDP Communication Example'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text("Received Data: $receivedData"), // Display received data

            // Dropdown for selecting current location
            Text("Select Current location"),
            DropdownButton(
              value: selectedCurrent,
              icon: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
              items: cities.map((String items) {
                return DropdownMenuItem(
                  value: items,
                  child: Text(items),
                );
              }).toList(),
              onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                setState(() {
                  selectedCurrent = newValue!;
                });
                print(selectedCurrent);
              },
            ),
            // Dropdown for selecting destination
            Text("Select Destination"),
            DropdownButton(
              value: selectedDestination,
              icon: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
              items: cities.map((String items) {
                return DropdownMenuItem(
                  value: items,
                  child: Text(items),
                );
              }).toList(),
              onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                setState(() {
                  selectedDestination = newValue!;
                });
                print(selectedDestination);
              },
            ),

            TextFormField(
              controller: ipAddressController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "IP Address"),
            ),
            TextFormField(
              controller: portController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Port"),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _initialize();
              },
              child: Text('Initialize UDP Communication'),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _sendData();
              },
              child: Text('Send Data'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Any possible fixes?

Comment: What's the return value of sendto?

Comment: The sendto function returns the number of characters that are sent. I independently tested the send function from cpp, I see no issues there. I also independently tested the receiving from flutter app, No issues there either.

i tested them using netcat and echo in my terminal

Comment: Remove the path calculation logic and send manually calculated data. That is do a unit test. I would define a network socket class that can be sparately tested. Then I would test the path logic with console io and pipe input and output files. Finally couple the network class and path logic in main project.